# Usage issue with HTMLAjaxCommandButton

Tags: javascript, ajax, button, command

I am using HTMLAjaxCommandButton with methodexpression set for action. When this button is clicked, corresponding action gets invoked but what I'm trying now is to submit the form before the binded method gets invoked. For that purpose, I was using setOnClick method of HTMLAjaxCommandButton to provide Javascript for form submission. This is working fine in firefox but has issues in Chrome. Reason being action expression also gets converted to Ajax call present in onClick method on Button. So, effectively now we have two methods getting called up from onClick. Chrome do not like this!

Anyone has idea about it or a better way to deal with this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. I removed setAjaxSingle and setImmediate for HtmlAjaxCommandButton. Now, everything works fine. We don't need to have javascript for form submission.